# What is Keras Early stopping looking at

Tags: keras, early-stopping

I am conditioning earlystop in val_loss like below:

```
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                          min_delta=0.0001,
                          patience=3,
                          verbose=1,
                          mode='auto')
```

It stops correctly after no improvement in 3 epoch but i dont see where it gets loss as 1.73011 from ? Can anyone help ? Also notice it starts this even after the 1st epoch , shouldn't it wait at least two epochs to compare and then declare 'no improvement(reduction)' in loss?

[Training Process Epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlpOu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is based on how you've set your parameters, you can simply increase the `patience` so that the callback observes results for more epochs before stopping the training process.

These are what each parameter means:

```
    monitor: Quantity to be monitored.
    min_delta: Minimum change in the monitored quantity to qualify as an improvement, i.e. an absolute change of less than min_delta, will count as no improvement.
    patience: Number of epochs with no improvement after which training will be stopped.
    verbose: verbosity mode.
    mode: One of {"auto", "min", "max"}. In min mode, training will stop when the quantity monitored has stopped decreasing; in "max" mode it will stop when the quantity monitored has stopped increasing; in "auto" mode, the direction is automatically inferred from the name of the monitored quantity.
    baseline: Baseline value for the monitored quantity. Training will stop if the model doesn't show improvement over the baseline.
    restore_best_weights: Whether to restore model weights from the epoch with the best value of the monitored quantity. If False, the model weights obtained at the last step of training are used.
```

ref: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is using some default baseline value or calculating a baseline (somehow!) when you are not explicitly supplying one.

Explicitly make the ***baseline = None*** and try.